# Adding Canonical Tags Using Openelement

Tags: canonical-url, meta-tags, tags

It appears that this format is generally found when adding canonical tags to a webpage `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com" />`    However, using Open element the href is replaced by content ie `<meta <link rel="canonical" content="example.com" />`.  Can anyone tell me if this is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

`<meta <link rel="canonical" content="example.com" />` is invalid HTML and won't be recognized by any search engine.   You can't have tags nested inside other tags like that.

Even if that is a typo in your question and you meant something else, it is still problematic.

- Canonical URLs must be fully qualified, not just a domain name. `https://example.com/page.html` should be used as a canonical URL but never `example.com`
- Canonical URLs cannot be specified by meta tag, only by link tag so this will not be understood: `<meta rel="canonical" content="https://example.com/" />`
- Canonical URLs link tags need a `href` not a `content` attribute. So this will not be understood: `<link rel="canonical" content="https://example.com/" />`